# Strange plant growing in my pot

Tags: identification, weeds

A strange plant popped up in my pot. It's about a metre and a half tall, skinny and has yellow green leaves which tastes minty, is serrated. It never flowered but has seeds on it too which also taste minty. I took a few bites but it has no side effects except leaving a fresh minty taste in my mouth. Is it edible? Can you help identify this plant. Perhaps it's dropped into my pot by a bird.

[image]

Comment: Eating unknown plants is not a good idea, if you want to live for a long time. Most (but not all!) poisonous plants don't taste very nice, but there are plenty of species that can make you ill even if they don't kill you.

Comment: Interesting id problem. Maybe it is in a family of plants that has tiny flowers. You don't see them easily but they are there. In this respect they are like the dock family. A helpful detail would be a description of the seed, as detailed as you can be, but "round" or "flat sides, with points" would be good too. Ideally a photo at magnification, if possible.

Comment: Where do you live? Which continent?